# iOS Sandbox - Can't purchase a consumable item twice

Tags: ios, objective-c, app-store-connect

Problem: I'm trying to test in app purchases with a sandbox account, but every time I try to purchase a consumable item twice, I get the following error message:

```
You've already purchased this In-App Purchase but it hasn't been downloaded. 
                         [Environment: Sandbox]
```

This only happens when using iOS < 6. I've read that this may be a sandbox-related issue. Does anyone know if there is any truth to that statement?

I'm sure that the following call is being made to complete the first transaction:

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction]
```

I've tried making this call as well to flush out the queue with no luck:

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue]  restoreCompletedTransactions];
```

I'm also making sure that before testing the iAP, I'm logged out of the iTunes store. In addition, I've also checked that the build and version number are in the Summary pane of my Target in Xcode.

Comment: are you 100% sure it is consumable product...?

Comment: I am experiencing this for iOS 6 and 7 and non-consumable products. Have you figured out how to solve that?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar situation that I would get this message and then crash if I tried to purchase it again. To me, it looks like this is just a message that **finishTransaction** hasn't completed (for whatever reason). According to my logs, it grants a **SKTransactionStateFailed** updated transaction, allowing me to resend the **finishTransaction**.

I then check in within my app that it has in fact downloaded the data/purchase BOOL/whatever and present a user interface if they need to download it again. Don't seem to have a problem with subsequent downloads.

To prevent the crashing, I included:

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] removeTransactionObserver:self];
```

Answer (score 0):

problem is probably this missing line in your code

`[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];`

i get the same error a few days ago. and this line fix the problem for me. this line adds observer for the in-apps.